# How to deploy tika-server-1.7.jar on tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, war, apache-tika

How to deploy tika-server as WAR file, under a servlet container Tomcat?
I prefer to deploy without using in maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of February 2015, this isn't possible. The Tika Server is only available as a runnable jar.

There is ongoing work to do a war version as well, that's being tracked on [TIKA-894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-894). If this matters to you, your best bet is to review [the enhancement ticket for that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-894), then join the [dev list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tika-dev/) and volunteer to help finish it off.